# JavaScript toDataURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to obtain data URL of an image so that I use a **dataurl** function of canvas but it giving me an error for **dataurl** function.

[Please check here](https://embed.plnkr.co/0u8vdd7AsoM2lbp4bVOk/)

Comment: Always try to post the problem along with the code _here, on stackoverflow_. If the external link that you have pasted here goes dead, the question isn't very helpful to anyone in the future facing the same problem. Look for `<>` button when you want to embed code in your question.

Comment: k i will do from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `toDataURL` exists on the [*canvas*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), not the *context*, so call `c.toDataURL` in your example. Note that you will then have to deal with "tainted canvases" in your example, but that's another question...

Answer (score 0):

(SOLVED !)
you didn't tell the problem completely but ...
I've encountered with this problem & i solved it . First of ALL you should check that you have included the CDN HTML2CANVAS.js in your script links in your head  tag . To do this you should paste this script in your  head  tag , after the jquery CDN :
(add this script below into your  head  tag )

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

in this CDN , the function 'toDataURL' have been defined & if you go to this link and search (with CTRL+F) on this script page , you could find toDataURL function . (which has been defined in this CDN)
NOW my head tag is like this below and it works :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
```